# Delete Storage File (Image) C# metro apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have an issue, in my app m using or show images in Gridview which are saved in local folder of my app, i want to delete these images by select them, but issue is that these images are in use and in windows when anything (file or image) open or in use so it should not delete from drive. and i want to delete to images from hard disk. m using or access these images in GridView through URI path in BitmapImage. like this

private ImageSource _image = null;
this._image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/RecentImages/"), this._imagePath));

And m trying to delete
please tell me how to stop or Dispose this link between GridView and StorageFile
or how to delete image from Storage Device??

Comment: When you open images, after reading image data, close the stream of image file.

Comment: how to close image stream sir?

Comment: these images are used in my Gridview as a recent activity, and these are open everytime on my main page

Comment: and m using URI path to get these images not my stream sir.

Comment: Pls check my code below. I'm not sure if following is going to stably work with metro, but it solves my problems on [Newgen](http://newgen.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that no other app loads same image at same time.
Here's a way to close image file stream after loading it in memory.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the bitmap.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The path.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static BitmapSource GetBitmap(string path)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path)) return null;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        byte[] bytArray = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        ms.Write(bytArray, 0, bytArray.Length); ms.Position = 0;
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.StreamSource = ms;
        bi.EndInit();
        return bi;
    }
```